# mysql show how many connections to a table

Tags: mysql

How can I see how many requests my mysql-table has answered? I need something like a "visitor-counter". I tried with

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS
```

but that doesn´t show me how many connections were made to my table! How´s that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see your process list using SHOW PROCESSLIST

If you want to see data for table you can try:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE `INFO` LIKE '%your_table%'
```

but of course it will display data not only for your table but also if any field or value include your table name it will be also displayed.

If you have simple queries you can limit it do:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE `INFO` LIKE '%FROM your_table%'
```

what makes that less rows will be displayed and almost those one strictly connected to your table